# Share image from main app to imessage extension and vice versa in swift

Tags: swift, image, target, imessage-extension

I want to fetch a image from main app and share this image via iMessage extension.iMessage has created new target.So how to share this image from main app to this new iMessage extension as both have two different targets in same application.

Comment: let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [imageURL], applicationActivities: nil) . use this type

Comment: i want to implement iMessage extension in my app.So i want to see the images in the keypad when iMessage is opened in my device.